# Do all android devices contain the same documents path

Tags: android, directory

I am using the directory obtained by this code under the assumption that all android devices have this exact path. Is this true?

```
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to care if this path exists or not as long as it's managed by the Android API. Maybe the exact path could change on different devices, but as long as you refer to it by this environment variable it will be good as it will refer to the good folder for the concerned device.

Comment: Is there any documentation to support your answer? I'm just curious because it's important that this path exists.

Comment: That's just how environment variables works. Android has a set of environment variables that are filled by the device's manufacturer for their own device. So, there will always be a folder corresponding to the path in the environment variable, even if it can be different on different devices, there is no problem as long as you use that variable to refer to it and not a raw coded path.

Answer (score 0):

No. All device manufacturer have different path. for sdcard and internal memory.
refer below code for finding path -

```
Map<String, File> externalLocations = ExternalStorage.getAllStorageLocations();
File externalSdCard = externalLocations.get(ExternalStorage.EXTERNAL_SD_CARD);
```

using above you will get path where you internal and external storage is available.